# How many size $s$ circuits from $\{0, 1\}^n \to \{0, 1\}$ are there?

Tags: combinatorics, circuits

For simplicity, we can assume that only NAND gates are allowed.  An asymptotically correct solution is all I really need.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you think? What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Each of the $s$ gates is connected to two other gates or inputs, for a total of $(s+n)^2$ possibilities. This gives a rough upper bound which isn't tight, but is good enough for many purposes, for example to show that some functions require circuits of size $\Omega(2^n/n)$. See [Steurer's notes](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~dsteurer/toc13/lectures/3/), for example.